# Is there a way to use Android system generated notifications in our app

Tags: android, push-notification, batterylevel

I'm creating an app and its mainly depends on the battery notification which we receive when our battery level is low like 15%. However I know how to get the battery level, but I thought what if there is a way to use the existing notification based on which we can add features.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Android system generated notifications'?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "use the existing notification based on which we can add features"?

Comment: @Denny When our phone battery reduces to 15% we automatically get an notification alert if you see that notification it would also indicate it is android system telling you about the battery level.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Since android system already gives us the notification of battery level, which I require in my app based on which I can go-head and build some features of my app. e.g when battery level is 15% or 5% my app does some work. 

 But how can i this default notification (e.g 15% or 5% by android system) to make use in my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a battery low broadcast that you can use, check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) (scroll to "Monitor Significant Changes in Battery Level")

Comment: What more do you want then?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "existing notification", insofar as the thousands of Android device models can do whatever they want when the battery is low. Not all will raise a `Notification`.

For those that do raise a `Notification`, there is nothing for you to "use":

- A `Notification` is a Java object; your app cannot access Java objects from other processes
- A `Notification` is configured by a variety of pieces of data; you have no idea what an individual device will use

You are certainly welcome to putter around the AOSP and see exactly what is used for low-battery indications in "stock" Android. Just bear in mind that what you find there is not going to be used on all Android devices and none of it will be part of the Android SDK (other than the generic `Notification` API).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it helped me understand more on Android system notifications differing across devices henceforth there isn't a way to make use of the notification for our app . If we ever want any such notification or alerts we would create one and use it in our app. This would be the approach right @CommonsWare

Comment: @AjayDeepak: "If we ever want any such notification or alerts we would create one and use it in our app" -- correct.

Comment: I saw your officehourschat program in order to join the chat when its happening how I should subscribe . Please let me know, I would like to make use of the opportunity.

Comment: @AjayDeepak: Stack Overflow is not really the place for that. Email wares@commonsware.com for questions about the Warescription program.